# Any good examples on how to add DROP DOWN list as header filter in slick Grid?

Tags: jquery, slickgrid

Any good examples on how to add DROP DOWN list as header filter in slick Grid??

I'm using slick grid to generate a grid.? any ideas or examples folks ?

using this sample http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example-header-row.html

Comment: found this http://danny-sg.github.io/slickgrid-spreadsheet-plugins/examples/example-1-everything.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

found this http://danny-sg.github.io/slickgrid-spreadsheet-plugins/examples/example-1-everything.htm

not exactly what i had in mind but coded based on this example